# How to read a one lined CSV in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have been working on a dummy dataset recently and i found out that the data provided to me was all in single line. A similiar example for the same is depicted as follows:

```
Name,Age,Gender,Occupation A,10,M,Student B,11,M,Student C,11,F,Student
```

i want to import the data and obtain an output as follows:

```
Name  Age  Gender  Occupation
 A    10     M       Student
 B    11     M       Student
 C    12     F       Student
```

a case may arise that a value might be missing. a logic is required to import such data. Can anyone help me out to build a logic behind the import of such data sets.

i tried the normal import but it really didn't helped. just imported the file by `read.csv()` function and it didn't gave me an expected result.

EDIT: what if the data is like:

```
Name,Age,Gender,Occupation ABC XYZ,10,M,Student B,11,M,Student C,11,F,Student
```

and i want an output like:

```
  Name     Age  Gender  Occupation
 ABC XYZ    10     M       Student
   B        11     M       Student
   C        12     F       Student
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could read your file in with `readLines`, turn spaces into line breaks, and then read it with `read.csv`:

```
# txt <- readLines("my_data.txt") # with a real data file
txt <- readLines(textConnection("Name,Age,Gender,Occupation A,10,M,Student B,11,M,Student C,11,F,Student"))

read.csv(text=gsub(" ","\n",txt))
```

output

```
  Name Age Gender Occupation
1    A  10      M    Student
2    B  11      M    Student
3    C  11      F    Student
```

Comment: well this is an example of data only. i am provided with about a million entry data. i cannot copy whole of the data and add it up to the R console.

Comment: this is just an example. Use `readLines("my_data.txt")` instead

Comment: what if the data is like:

Name,Age,Gender,Occupation ABC XYZ,10,M,Student B,11,M,Student C,11,F,Student

and i want an output like:

    Name      Age  Gender  Occupation
 ABC XYZ    10     M       Student
       B          11     M       Student
       C          12     F       Student

Comment: in that case, there is a serious problem with your data production, because it is a very ambiguous format (spaces have different meanings and they are not quoted). How can the machine knows whether "ABC" belongs to "Occupation ABC" or to " ABC XYZ"? I would advise you disambiguate your data at the production stage. That said, if you are sure that only Name can contain spaces, you could use `read.csv(text=gsub("((.*?,){3}\\S+) ","\\1\n",txt,perl = TRUE))`

Comment: thanks @scoa i think i can now figure it out. But i have to change my code every time for reading different kinds of data. I thought there could be a generic logic behind import of such data in R. but in that case i need to build one.

Answer (score 9):

If you have millions of records, you will probably want to speed up this process, so I suggest using `data.table`'s `fread` instead of `read.csv`, which can also take a shell command to pre-process the file before reading in R, and `sed` will be a lot faster then doing the string manipulation in R.

Eg if you have this CSV stored at `/tmp/x.csv`, you can try something like:

```
> data.table::fread("sed 's/ /\\n/g' /tmp/x.csv")
   Name Age Gender Occupation
1:    A  10      M    Student
2:    B  11      M    Student
3:    C  11      F    Student
```

Comment: Thanks @daroczig but i wanted to do it by the base packages of R. for this i have to import data.table package. though the information is very helpful.

Comment: What stops you loading the `data.table` package? I mean I am not sure why is it better to do something in base R, if there are more convenient and faster ways to solve the problem -- especially with many rows. I am really interested in your arguments.

Comment: i wanted to create a logic for the program in Base R. I know it is convenient to use the external packages but i am restricted to use the base R packages only.